# Phototransistor Optocouplers datasheet

Tags: datasheet

I would like your help in understanding whether [this phototransistor](https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/52722/FAIRCHILD/H11AA1.html) meets the requirements of the project I am supposed to do.
I am having a little trouble getting the following informations from the datasheet:

**1)** How much input voltage can it support? If, for example, my signal is a sinewave with amplitude [0-3]V, will it break the component or not?
(I think this parameter is the "Breakdown Voltage Collector to Emitter"(?))

**2)** What frequency must the input sinewave have to be within the operating bandwidth of the phototransistor? In other words: what is the max freq. of the input signal that I apply?

Thank you all in advance.

EDIT
I forgot to write that in output I want a signal containing peaks when the input sinusoid crosses zero.
I've seen it done on some videos on Youtube and I would like to replicate it but using an input signal like the one described above, but I've never used this component so I had some doubts about it

Comment: the input signal is applied to the LED, not to the phototransistor

Comment: 1. 30v limit. you need a positive dc-offset of the LED's Vf to reproduce the sine wave, but note that OCs are not very linear/analog (they are meant to switch on/off), so results may vary. 2. Based on load, it can toggle at between 1Mhz and 1Khz.

Comment: Can’t answer the question because we don’t know what the project is. More details or clarity please.

Comment: Do you require a sine wave as an output? Note that this optocoupler is not meant to replicate a sine wave signal. With a sine wave used as an input the output will be a series of pulses with a short off period centered near the zero crossing point. There are some specialty optocouplers that can replicate a linear signal, however to achieve accuracy these require additional circuitry

Comment: This is an optocoupler, not a phototransistor. An optocoupler *contains* a phototransistor, but it no more is a phototransistor than a salad is lettuce: it's an important part, but there are other parts too.

Comment: I just edited the post adding the missing informations, as suggested by @RussellH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For (1), note that the input drives a pair of back-to-back LEDs. It's not about the voltage: your input drive **current** needs to be limited to +/100mA continuous, or +/-1A peak to prevent damage to the device.

How do limit that current? The LED pair has a forward voltage of about +/-1.2V, typical for an infrared LED. For a 3V waveform you will need a series resistor, calculated to give enough IR drop to achieve the desired LED current.

What value for the resistor? This depends on the LED drive you need, which in turn depends on two factors:

- the device **current transfer ratio** (CTR) given in the datasheet.
- how much output current you require at the transistor

There are several versions of this part that have current transfer ratios from 10% to 100%. Which one you choose depends on both how sensitive you need the input to be, and how much transistor current you require.

If for example you need 10mA at the output, and you choose the 100% CTR version, you will need to drive the LED with 10mA. With a 3V input, a series resistor of 180 ohm (that is, [3V-1.2V]/10mA) would yield 10mA at the LED, and also at the output since CTR is 100%. This is well within the device spec and would not damage it.

For (2), the bandwidth is not specified. Instead, the **switching speed** is given in Fig. 7. The switch-on time is about 1us; the switch-off time depends on the load resistor attached to the photo-transistor, which is at minimum about 1.2us per Fig. 7. Adding the two times together we get 2.2us, or 450kHz for this device.

You added that you want to make pulses at the zero-cross point. To do that precisely you'll need to pre-process the input signal. As it is, the emitter LED will light when the voltage is higher than 1.2V. You could adjust this by adding a Schottky diode in series to raise the forward voltage to about 1.5V. Then you would have a square waveform that's roughly aligned with the 3V sine.

You could also add a series capacitor. This will differentiate the sine to a cosine (more or less) and thus light up when the input dI/dt is at max (at the rise or fall of the sine.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. I take the opportunity to ask if I understand the working principle correctly: if I use the optocoupler as it is, the Vthreshold = Vforward of the IR LEDs, right? So: if Vin applied > Vforward then the LED turns on and Vo = 0 because the transistor is on and therefore the output is shorted to GND. Otherwise, if Vin applied < Vforward then the LED remains off and therefore the transistor is not conducting (open circuit) and Vo = Vcc.    To change/choose the Vthreshold I add electronics to the input stage (schottky as you suggested etc.).

Comment: It’s better to think of current. When there is current in the LED, the transistor turns on and passes current. For a 100% CTR device, 10mA of LED current translates to 10mA at the output (assuming the output is supplied with a voltage. )